# C++ Constructor won't pass string - no constructor defined

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I am trying to create an object of "Player" inside "PlayerManager" and I am getting the error in VS2010:

`Error  1   error C2512: 'Player::Player' : no appropriate default constructor available    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory   631 1   Server`

Player.h:

```
#ifndef _PLAYER_H
#define _PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(const string &name);
~Player(void);


private:
    string name_;
};

#endif
```

Here is the constructor in Player.cpp:

```
Player::Player(const string &name)
{

}
```

PlayerManager.h:

```
'#ifndef _PLAYERMANAGER_H
#define _PLAYERMANAGER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

class PlayerManager
{
public:
    PlayerManager(void);
    ~PlayerManager(void);

private:
    vector<Player> players;
};

#endif'
```

Here is where I create the object in PlayerManager.cpp:

```
PlayerManager::PlayerManager(void)
{
        Player test("Hello");
        players.resize(1000);
    for(int i=0; i < 960; i++){
        players.push_back(test);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it is ignoring the string "Hello", I have tried creating a string object but gives same error.

I have also tried without adding the const & in the constructor but gives same error.

Any help would be appreciated, spend hours searching for an answer. Apologies if the layout is incorrect as this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the class definition of `PlayerManager`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I have added PlayerManager and shown where I used resize.

Comment: I have removed the players.resize and now my code works as I expected, thanks for quick answers.

Comment: Got it. The `resize` is your problem. Use `reserve` instead.

Comment: ¤ The `resize` call is not reserving buffer space, it's sizing the vector: if it was empty it now gains 1000 `Player` objects. After that the loop adds 960 more, for a total of 1960 `Player` objects. Compilation error: because `resize` adds objects, which you have specified should be default-constructed. *Remove* the `resize` call to fix that. Then, consider removing also C-ism `void` as formal arg, remember that `_PLAYER_H` is a reserved name since it starts with underline followed by uppercase, and **do not** have `using namespace std;` in the global namespace in a header. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class `std::vector` requires that the class you use it with has a default constructor<sup>1</sup>. You'll need to provide one for your class.

If you really don't want to provide one, you can give an instance of your class to `vector` in it's constructor call, so that it will use that instance instead of trying to default-construct one:

```
vector v(initialsize, Player("")); // or you can pass whatever string you want the default item to have
```

If the vector that you are using to store `Player`s is a member variable, you'll need to pass it the default `Player` to use in the initialiser list:

```
PlayerManager::PlayerManager() : players(initialsize, Player("")) { // assuming the vector is named players
    .... 
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As **R. Martinho Fernandes** and **Kerrek SB** have pointed out in the comments, a default constructor is only required for this particular constructor of `vector` (the one that takes an initial size and when you don't give it a default instance) and the member function `resize` when called with a single argument. If you use the constructor that takes iterators or a `const Allocator&`, or if you use `resize` with the second argument, then you don't need a DC.

Comment: Please add that OP has forgotten to initialize *name_*.

Comment: @Beginner you don't need to initalise strings.

Comment: @Beginnner I had stripped down the code to show the problem areas.

Comment: (Not default) Constructor is empty. It has a parameter but makes no use of it. Or I'm totally blind?

Comment: @Beginner that's not an error, it will compile and run fine (unless you have your compiler set to fail when it detects unused arguments).

Comment: @SethCarnegie yes, but I thought it could be also useful.

Comment: The default constructor requirement is only for this particular constructor and `resize`. `vector` works fine with non-default-constructible types otherwise.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Even more specifically, you only need a DC for the *one-argument* version of `resize()`. The two-argument version copies a prototype.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes and KerrekSB, I think I have summed up your points in a note at the bottom. Thanks.